# save ip in a list from conversion

Tags: c++, string, android-ndk, char

The function would read a line of DNS server information and check if it is quad or not and store in a list.
The line would be :`8.8.8.8 , 8.8.4.4`

The issue is it would read the first one correctly and prints the decimal value :134744072
but for second it would be:`1476921352`

please help with the code...

hence pszString would read the whole line and store each address in a list dnsip[i]

```
int SetDNSserver(char* pszString) {
    memset( dnsip, 0, sizeof(dnsip) );  //clear out old

    const char *p;
    int i=0;
    char *nameDottedQuad ;
    std::string dottedquad;
    int flag=0;

    for( p = pszString; *p; ++p ) {
        if( isdigit(*p) || *p == '.' ) {
            //copy the  value to dottedquad
            dottedquad+=*p;
            FREE_SAFE(nameDottedQuad);
            nameDottedQuad = strdup(dottedquad.c_str());
            if(isValidIpAddress(nameDottedQuad)) {
                //save it in a list
                while(i<10) {
                    dnsip[i] = inet_addr(nameDottedQuad);

                    #ifdef ANDROID_DEBUG
                        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, DEBUG_TAG," DNSSERVER:%d",dnsip[i]);
                    #endif

                    i++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            //DisplayNot dotted quad ");
        }
    }

    static bool isValidIpAddress(char *ipAddress) {
        struct sockaddr_in sa;
        int result = inet_pton(AF_INET, ipAddress, &(sa.sin_addr));
        return result != 0;
    }
}

#define FREE_SAFE(x)              { if (((x) != NULL)) \
                                  {  free(x); (x) = NULL; } }
```

Comment: You don't show any allocation for `nameDottedQuad`. Your `FREE_SAFE` might be checking for `NULL` but it may not be zeroing anyhting out, so you may have some residual data. `strdup` is returning more characters than the previous call and depending on the memory layout, if you haven't zero'd this could be what you're seeing.  Also, you should try and use std::string for everything. It's safer and you wouldn't have these issues.

Comment: So you mean to  empty dottedquad after every use? If so how to do that???

Comment: Not dottedQuad, but nameDottedQuad in FREE_SAFE. It sounds as if FREE_SAFE does the following...checks if pointer is NULL and if so return, otherwise free it. But what you need it to do is after you free it, zeroize the memory (nameDottedQuad[] = 0x00, 0x00, ...).  I don't know if you wrote FREE_SAFE, but if you did you could change it to pass in a size parameter or determine the size using `strlen` since it was allocated with `strdup`(if you do that maybe rename it to STR_FREE).  Before you do anything in FREE_SAFE see if that's the problem and zeroize it after the call.

Comment: zeroize the memory ? sorry Im not that good in c++..thats like deallocating the memory??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were lot of issues and one was parsing issue.FREE_SAFE was not used correctly.The logical approach to this has to be changed and its working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

1. what is FREE_SAFE doing ?
2. You might want to check the result of inet_addr(...) like
   if ( ulAddr == INADDR_NONE ) { // print error message }

BTW, you don't need to check in every iteration if the IP address is valid. You can wait until you are done processing the input string completely and then check just once if it is a valid IP address.

Comment: The idea is t read the line of IP in a line which could be separated by commas,space ,etc and then add it to a list...I dont know how to check IP after processing?

Comment: #define FREE_SAFE(x)           { if (((x) != NULL)) \
                                  {  free(x); (x) = NULL; } }